# SQL select with dynamic counts

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table `foo` from which I'd like to select N rows from each category

```
create table foo(name text, category text);

 name | category 
------+----------
 aaa  | cat1
 bbb  | cat1
 ccc  | cat2
 ddd  | cat2
 eee  | cat2
```

Now I'd like to pick from foo given a number of categories

```
 category | count 
----------+-------
 cat2     |     2
 cat1     |     1
```

The result should be 3 rows (ties could be resolved randomly or by any order)

```
 name
------
 ccc
 ddd
 aaa

-- wrong, not taking counts into account
with t as (select * from (values ('cat1', 1), ('cat2', 2)) as 
t(category, count)) select name from foo, t where foo.category = t.category;

 name 
------
 aaa
 bbb
 ccc
 ddd
 eee
```

I could do this with multiple queries, but I think I am missing something very obvious and the select can be done with a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
FROM categories c,
LATERAL (
  select * FROM foo
  where foo.category = c.category 
  ORDER BY random()
  LIMIT c.count
) x
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e0f14/7

Answer (score 1):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
select foo.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by foo.category order by foo.category) as seqnum
      from foo join
           t
           on foo.category = t.category
     ) t
where seqnum <= t.cnt;
```